# Morphism of locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules and projection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a proper smooth variety over a finite field. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module and $\psi:\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ be an injection and locally splitting. At the level of stalks, there are projection maps $\pi_p:\mathcal{F}_p\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ such that $\pi_p\circ\psi_p$ is the identity. Do they determine a surjective morphism $\pi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that need not be the case: for example, there is a locally splitting injection ${\mathcal O}_X\to{\mathcal O}_X(1)\oplus{\mathcal O}_X(1)$ on ${\mathbb P}^1$ (belonging to a short exact sequence $0\to {\mathcal O}_X\to{\mathcal O}_X(1)\oplus{\mathcal O}_X(1)\to{\mathcal O}_X(2)\to 0$). It does not split globally since $\text{Hom}_{{\mathcal O}_X}({\mathcal O}_X(1),{\mathcal O}_X)\cong\text{H}^0(X;{\mathcal O}_X(-1))=0$.

Comment: Your short exact sequence is not defined since you don't say what the morphisms are.

Comment: I'm sorry - I meant the image of the Koszul resolution of the residue field under the associated sheaf functor.

Comment: Dear Hanno, if the user  knew about Koszul resolutions he probably would be expert enough not to ask his question :-) And anyway there is no canonical resolution of the residue field, so you still have to be more explicit. But  I'll let the OP decide if he is satisfied with this answer (which is excellent once one is convinced that such an  exact sequence exists).

Comment: Dear Georges, thank you for your comments - yes, let's wait for the OPs reaction. I agree however that most likely details will have to be added, but I'm only writing from my phone at the moment so can't elaborate right now.